# How to swap src with id in javascript onmouseenter?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the image to change when I mouse over using javascript. The img src should be swapped with the ids.  The problem is that something is going wrong with the loop and when I run this, it will swap the images but only with image "images/h6.jpg".  So all three have the same pic.

HTML:

```
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Image Rollovers</h1>
    <ul id="image_rollovers">
        <li><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="images/h4.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="" id="images/h5.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="" id="images/h6.jpg"></li>
    </ul>        
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
var $ = function (id) { 
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}
//ONLOAD EVENT HANDLER      
window.onload = function () {

    //GET IMAGE TAGS
    var listNode = $("image_rollovers");
    var imageList = listNode.getElementsByTagName("img");

    //PROCESS EACH IMAGE
    var i, imageNode, image;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < imageList.length ; i++ ){

        //1. GET IMG TAG
        imageNode = imageList[i];

        //2. PRELOAD IMAGE FROM IMG TAG
        image = new Image();
        image.src = imageNode.getAttribute("id");

        //3. ATTACH EVENT HANDLERS (onmouseover & onmouseout) TO IMG TAG
        imageNode.onmouseenter = function (evt) {
            var img = this;
            img.src = imageNode.getAttribute("id");

            if (!evt) evt = window.event;
            if( evt.preventDefault ) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            } else {
                evt.returnValue = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `imageNode.getAttribute("id");` will be the value the same value for each item. Hence it changes on each iteration so only has the last value is used on each event handler. This is why it only works for the last image. Rather use `img.src = this.getAttribute("id")` so we are using the specific element's `id` that is having the event triggered.

```
imageNode.onmouseenter = function (evt) {
    var img = this;
    img.src = this.getAttribute("id");
    ...
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vf9q1j9d/). *Note make sure to inspect the elements to see the `src` changes.*

Comment: That's it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pecijo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

- Don't use `ID` to store arbitrary data, use `data-*` attribute instead.

```
 <img src="images/h1.jpg" data-src="images/h4.jpg" alt="">
```

- No need to wait for the window.onload.
- Don't create **functions within loops** (Issue with overwriting values)

```
function $(id) { 
  return document.getElementById(id); 
}

var listNode  = $("image_rollovers");
var imageList = listNode.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i, imageNode, image;


// (Don't make fn inside loops)
function swapSrc() {
  this.src = this.dataset.src;
}


for (i=0 ; i<imageList.length; i++) {

  imageNode = imageList[i];
  //PRELOAD
  image = new Image();
  image.src = imageNode.dataset.src;
  // Attach mouseenter listener
  imageNode.addEventListener("mouseenter", swapSrc, false);
}
```

Comment: My textbook has the function for a similar onclick event inside a loop.  Any particular reason I should stay away from it?

Comment: @user2400244 here it's explained very well: https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop - and **you'll recognize the exact issue you were facing** - overwritten values outputs..